# HAPI always seems to timeout on searches

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I have a HAPI instance set up in it's out of the box configuration. I've loaded 370,000 instances of Basic into it, and each one has a value for Basic.Meta.Profile.

I try to do a search for all instances of a given profile:

```
{{URL}}/Basic?_profile=http://stelar.org/StructureDefinition/stelar/profile/questionResponse
```

But I always get 504 gateway timeout returned.
I have no idea if it's the search or the bundling of the results that's taking too long, but I'm not really sure how I go about fixing it. It doesn't seem like a lot of instances to search through, and it's one of the standard search parameters, so I was kind of expecting it to work out of the box.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what might be wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem now. Did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Sorry @MikeB but I never actually got to the bottom of this and I left the project before we needed to fix it.